# Visual Studio C++ - Can't reference a file inside the project to be parsed

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm following [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/2pv0Fbo-7ms?t=930) where in 15:30 an address inside the project repository is typed like this:

```
ShaderProgramSource source = ParseShader("res/shaders/Basic.shader");
```

I've followed the tutorial from the beginning letter by letter and this is where it all begins to crumble, I can't make the references to that .shader file work unless I put a ../ in the beginning:

```
ShaderProgramSource source = ParseShader("../res/shaders/Basic.shader");
```

and even when I do so MSVC or OpenGL don't complain but the code just doesn't work from here on out. My geometry gets rendered but the shader doesn't work. Is there any Visual Studio settings that is sabotaging me?

--

The res folder is inside my project directory:

[image]

And my working directory is:

[image]

Comment: If you have to add ../ to the file path that means the file is located in the parent folder of res/shaders/Basic. Maybe double check that directory and it's sub directories, make sure you know where the file is located and then call the function with the right path.

Comment: I edited the original post and added some screenshots.

Comment: This is odd that ../res works. I would not expect that for the information you posted. I would expect `res/shaders/Basic.shader` to work. I assume you have no code in your `c++` project that changes the working directory.

Comment: OpenGL functions are not getting syntax highlighted after this line so something is going very wrong here. OpenGL is horrible in error debugging so I don't know what exactly and why it quits complaining after I add the ../

Comment: `../res/shaders/Basic.shader` should not have anything to do with syntax highlighting at all. The shader is loaded at runtime.

Comment: Ok. I guess I've become a little pampered from learning to program JavaScript in VS Code with every extension I could get my hands on.